# Understanding the process of tightening head bolts properly

Tags: torque, cylinder-head, bolts

In some cars like some Peugeot & Citroen models, there is a specific stage during the process of tightening the head bolts. For example, in Haynes manual of Peugeot 405 it is stated that head bolts should be tightened as per the following stages:

Stage 1 - Tighten to 60 Newton Meters (nm)

**Stage 2 - Fully Slacken all the bolts in sequence**

Stage 3 - Re-tighten to 20 nm

Stage 4 - Angle tighten all the bolts a further 300 degrees

I have no problem understanding the stages 1, 3 & 4 but there is something about stage 2 that doesn't make sense to me.

Since it refers to angular tightening, it is clear that the head bolts are Torque-to-Yield bolts and as you know these bolts should not be re-used after being torqued down once. Torquing the bolts in stage 1 and slackening all of them in stage 2 and re-tightening them in stage 3 means re-using TY bolts and that doesn't make sense.
In addition to the bolts, the head gasket itself should not be re-used after being put under pressure once. Re-tightening the bolts, slackening & re-tightening them means the head gasket is compressed, decompressed and re-compressed which again defies logic.

So then, what is the main point behind the stage 2 of slackening the bolts in the middle of the process?

Here is a screenshot of the manual:

[image]

Comment: Right after what you are pointing out, it states "see text" ... what does the text say? I suspect there's more to what is going on in the reassembly part of the manual. My hunch is, the idea is to put a preload on the head gasket so as to crush it to size, then release it so when you put the 20 Nm back on, you a more true indicator of how much torque you are actually applying to the head bolt. As I said, just a hunch.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 - There is nothing special in the " see text " section. It only reminds us to slacken the bolts in the reverse order of the tightening. That's it.

Comment: These are "torque-to-yield" head bolts?

Comment: I would guess... That Stage 1, as @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 says, is to preload the gasket. That will reduce the give in the material, which in turn will give you a truer and more consistent amount of torque in Stage 3. When you do this, the gasket isn't removed or displaced, so it should stay "fitted" to the block and head. Finally, in Stage 4, you do the final tightening. If these are "torque-to-yield" bolts, this is the stage where they will yield.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 - Since they talk about 300 degrees angular tightening, they must be TTY bolts. They also mention something about discarding the bolts that are stretched more than a certain amount.

Comment: @dlu - Do you mean if the gasket is not preloaded, it might compress later and weaken the sealing between the block and the head?

Comment: @NarimanAsgharian - That's exactly what they (and I) are stating about the head gasket.

Comment: @NarimanAsgharian -- yes, or at the very least, that without the preload it may be hard to get a consistent amount of torque (pressure) across the assembly.